# No puedo visualizar las tablas de la base de datos master en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

No puedo visualizar las tablas de la base de datos **master** en mi *SQL Server 2008 R2*, ingrese a la base de datos con el usuario **sa** desde *SQL Server Management Studio 2008* y al expandir las tablas no veo ninguna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo darle una lectura a http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y por curiosidad, cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: Necesito revisar los logs de las transacciones realizadas, por un tema de Auditoria y no veo las tablas de la Base de Datos master